# How to get device name from aws device farm

Tags: aws-device-farm

I am running my testcases in appium nodejs custom environment. I selected the devicepool - "Top Devices" for unning the test. So it ran on 5 Android devices. So from the artifacts, how can I understand for which device each artifact is. Is there anyway I can get the device Name. I am able to get the UDID of android device, but not able to get the device name.

I checked "get-devices" via CLI, I am able to get the device ?Name from ARN, but UDID is not given there. So how can I know for which device this has been run.

Answer (score 1):

When you create devicefarm run on aws console, you can see the top pool devices in the Select Devices section. This will provide the details about the devices in top pool.
You can also get details of a devicepool from this api : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/devicefarm/get-device-pool.html

Comment: But if you have 10 devices, how will you know the result will be for which device